# simple issue for everyone to solve

Tags: variables, checkbox, printing, echo, checked

this is a very simple thing for me to solve but i'm stuck for some reason -

i've got a checkbox and it says "Checkbox Not Selected" -
when I check the checkbox, I want it to say "Checkbox Selected"...and when 
I do check it, it doesn't say anything - it still stays the same.
The code is printed below:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check1">
<?php
$c = "Checkbox Not Selected";
$b = "Checkbox Selected";
if (isset($_POST['check1'])) {
 echo $b;
    // Checkbox is selected
} else {
echo $c;
   // Alternate code
}

?>
```

How do I get it to say "Checkbox Selected" when after I check the checkbox?

Anyone willing to help out here?

Comment: hello! anyone home?!?! why am i not getting a response?

Comment: can anyone help me out please?